# Xcode 7 said I had errors I already fixed

Tags: xcode

So Xcode 7 was saying I had some errors, I fixed them, and the error stop sign went away. But then I re-opened my project the next day and found it was displaying all the same errors as before, even though the code had been fixed.

I restarted everything and the problem was still there. So I copy pasted each line to the line below then deleted the line that said it had an error and that solved the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what was happening?

Comment: Did you clear derived data and clean the project (cmd + shift + k)? That sometimes can fix things like this.

Comment: I've seen this too. I've commented out the problematic lines and Xcode keeps complaining about the errors! You really do have to clean the caches to get Xcode to stop it. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994